# Connect Four in Javascript - diagonal win check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a Connect Four game recently and I have problems to programm the diagonal win check. I just cant figure out how to get the win check....

My horizontal code looks like this :

```js
var winMoveSpalte = function() {
  var rowDummy = 3;
  var count = 0;
  for (var i_row = 0; i_row < 6; i_row++) {
    rowDummy = 3;
    count = 0;
    for (var i_col = 0; i_col < 7; i_col++) {
      if (rowDummy == 3 && settings.fieldSet[i_col][i_row] != 0) {
        winnerMove[count]['col'] = i_col; //x
        winnerMove[count]['row'] = i_row; //y
        count++;
      } else if (settings.fieldSet[i_col][i_row] != 0 && (rowDummy == settings.fieldSet[i_col][i_row])) {
        if (count < 4) {
          winnerMove[count]['col'] = i_col; //x
          winnerMove[count]['row'] = i_row; //y
          count++;
          if (count == 4) {
            for (var w = 0; w <= 3; w++) {
              $('div#feld .col_' + winnerMove[w]["col"] + '.row_' + winnerMove[w]['row']).addClass('winnerStone' + settings.activePlayer);
            }
            return settings.fieldSet[i_col][i_row];
          }
        }
      } else {
        count = 0;
        if (settings.fieldSet[i_col][i_row] != 0) {
          winnerMove[count]['col'] = i_col; //x
          winnerMove[count]['row'] = i_row; //y
          count++;
        }
      }
      rowDummy = settings.fieldSet[i_col][i_row];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To Check diagonal you just increment through every dimension of the array and check the state: eg `arr[n][n]`, `arr[n+1][n+1]`, `arr[n+2][n+2]`...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `arr[n][n]`, `arr[n+1][n-1]`, `arr[n+2][n-2]`, ... is also a diagonal

Comment: @MarcCompte Yep, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return the result you need:

```
function hasDiagonalWin(board, row, column) {
    var result = false;

    if(board[row][column] != 0) {
        // there are four possible directions of a win
        // if the top right contains a possible win
        if(row - 3 > -1 && column + 3 < numColumns) {
            result = board[row][column] == board[row - 1][column + 1] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row - 2][column + 2] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row - 3][column + 3]; 
        }
        // if the bottom right contains possible win
        if(row + 3 < numRows  && column + 3 < numColumns) {
            result = board[row][column] == board[row + 1][column + 1] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row + 2][column + 2] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row + 3][column + 3]; 
        }
        // if the bottom left contains possible win
        if(row + 3 < numRows && column - 3 > -1) {
            result = board[row][column] == board[row + 1][column - 1] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row + 2][column - 2] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row + 3][column - 3]; 
        }
        // if the top left contains a possible win
        if(row - 3 > -1 && column - 3 > -1) {
            result = board[row][column] == board[row - 1][column - 1] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row - 2][column - 2] &&
                     board[row][column] == board[row - 3][column - 3]; 
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```